# Prevent long Visual Studio test trace output with Moq Verify

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, moq, test-explorer

I wish to verify that a method has been called, using Moq's Verify method. Part of my test involves looping quite a large number of times, during which many other methods on my mock object, in addition to the one I want to verify, are called.

If the Verify assertion fails, in the Visual Studio Test Explorer output pane for the relevant test, in addition to the error message about the reason the verify fails, there is also listed every single other invocation that was made on the mock object, stretching into 1000s of lines. This makes the Test Explorer window become unusably laggy until the full exception detail has loaded, which can sometimes take minutes.

Is there any way to prevent Moq from listing all the other invocations that were performed? I only care about whether the Verify failed or not.

Contrived code to replicate the issue:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Foo();
    void Bar();
    void FooBar();
}

[TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
        {
            var myInterfaceMock = mock.Mock<IMyInterface>();
            var myInterfaceObj = myInterfaceMock.Object;

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                myInterfaceObj.Foo();
                myInterfaceObj.Bar();
            }

            myInterfaceMock.Verify(x => x.FooBar(), Times.Once());
        }
    }
}
```

Test Explorer output, goes on for 1000s of lines (sorry for the large size, high DPI screen):
[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not direct answer using `Verify()` but otherwise it prevents the Moq from listing all the other invocations that were performed.

It uses `Callback` to count the number of times the method `FooBar`was called. I don't know if you are gonna like this way?

---

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int expectedCount = 1;
    int actualCount = 0;
    
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {
        var myInterfaceMock = mock.Mock<IMyInterface>();
        var myInterfaceObj = myInterfaceMock.Object;
        myInterfaceMock.Setup(mi => mi.FooBar()).Callback(() => actualCount++);

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            myInterfaceObj.Foo();
            myInterfaceObj.Bar();
        }

        Assert.AreEqual( expectedCount, actualCount, $"Expected invocation on the mock was '{expectedCount}' times, but was called '{actualCount}' times");
    }
}
```

`Output:`

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>. Expected
> invocation on the mock was '1' times, but was called '0' times

Comment: Thank you - I will accept this answer, as it seems the only manageable workaround, similar to information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796785/moq-is-slow-to-verify-dependency-after-a-large-number-calls

Answer (score 1):

Verify throws an exception when the condition fails, so this seems like a case of simply catching the exception, parsing the message and then failing the test with the part of the message you want. This is trivial given the current format of the message:

```
var myInterfaceMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
var myInterfaceObj = myInterfaceMock.Object;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    myInterfaceObj.Foo();
    myInterfaceObj.Bar();
}

try
{
    myInterfaceMock.Verify(x => x.FooBar(), Times.Once());
}
catch (MockException me) 
{       
    throw new Exception(me.Message.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);       
}
```

results in:

[image]

How you fail the test is up to you, I've just thrown a new exception as MVP.
If it were me, I'd pop this into an extension method to keep the tests clean. You'd probably have to do a couple of them to handle the Verify overloads.

Comment: Thank you, this also would work, I've already accepted the first answer however. I wonder if the accepted answer would be more performant however, given that Moq would still be tracking 1000s of invocations with Verify?

Comment: `Verify` is likely to be slower by virtue of it doing more work, it's hard to get more efficient than an int counter. However it's that very reason why I'd be careful about a blanket approach to bypassing Verify. It's designed for this exact case, it takes into consideration inner mocks and what is verifiable. The accepted answer can be changed, it should reflect the one that best solves your issue. Personally I'd be opting for a single line change to my tests rather than adding counters, it doesn't seem clean.